# Android Notification onClick without starting intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent, notifications, clipboard

I have a notification and I want that onClick it copies some text to the clipboard.
The copy part etc. are all clear but I dont know if it's possible to attach a click event not an intent to the notification.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Intent + Activity with Theme.NoDisplay and put the code into onCreate of this activity. After you code just call finish() ...

Comment: Very nice idea, but then I get the error that I have to use AppCompat theme. Is there anything like that in AppCompat?

Comment: use normal Activity class not the one from AppCompat library(fix the imports or use directly android.app.Activity) as the base for this particular class

Comment: Thank you very much. Please post your solution as answer so I can accept it :)